# Не отображаются картинки на сайте vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не могу понять, почему не отображаются картинки на сайте. Использую vue, в локалке все отлично работает. Но как только уходит на сайт (прод), пропадают.
Так понимаю, что дело в хэширование? Тогда как это сделать?

```
    <div class='bestsellers-item' v-for='(item, index) in items' :key='index'>
     <div class='bestsellers-item__image'>
      <img :src='item.photo.url' alt='image'>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А у Вас картинки вообще лежат по путям, которые указаны? Нет картинок - нет и отображения...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Локально все отображается, с путями все ок

Comment: Ну дак покажите что там лежит? в item.photo.url

Comment: @Alex Так при чем тут локально? Вы же на сервере разворачиваете, на сервере должны быть ссылки открываемые. Просто сама ссылка с браузера открывается?